# Elasticsearch watcher email array value

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-watcher

I am working on ELK watcher to create an alert that sends an array of value transformed using 'transform' mapping.

```
"transform": {
   "script": "return [ err_yest : ctx.payload.aggregations.errorcount.buckets.collect { [err_count:it.doc_count, list_errors: it.errs.buckets.collect{[emsg:it.key,emsc:it.doc_count]}] } ]"
 },
```

Is there a way to print the array values in the body of email alert using any looping method? I tried groovy scripting, but got an error saying it's unsupported. All I could do is manually printing the values in array like below.

```
"body" : {
          "html": "<table width='400px' border='1'><thead><tr><th colspan='4'>Error Messages</th></tr><tr><th colspan='2'>Yesterday</th><th colspan='2'>Today</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.0.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.0.emsg}}</td><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.0.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.0.emsg}}</td></tr><tr><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.1.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.1.emsg}}</td><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.1.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.1.emsg}}</td></tr><tr><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.2.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.0.list_errors.2.emsg}}</td><td>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.2.emsc}}</td><td align='center'>{{ctx.payload.err_yest.1.list_errors.2.emsg}}</td></tr></tbody></table>"
        },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Mustache templating

The syntax is something like this :

```
{{#ctx.payload.err_yest}} {{#list_errors}} {{emsc}} {{/list_errors}}{{/ctx.payload.err_yest}}
```

This will loop over all the objects in `err_yest` then loop over all the `list_errors` for a `err_yest` object and display `esmc`

Comment: Dropping this for mustache documentation, some good examples here https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: This is great!  I used `{{#ctx.payload.hits.hits}} -- {{_source.message}}\n {{/ctx.payload.hits.hits}}`